# I cannot figure out the pointers with vector or a array

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having trouble with my computer science assignment. In this assignment we are using pointers with classes. And this is my very first time learning pointers and they are very difficult to understand for me. 
    I don't know if i'm doing right or no but here is what my professor said what i need to do with Push_back function. He said we need to use array but we can't push_back an item into array?

Am i doing something wrong with any function? Or should provide more details. Let me know.

```
/*Push an element to the end of the array:
        if sz == 0, reserve 1
        else if sz == space, reserve 2 * space
        assign x to the end of the array.
        increment sz*/
void push_back(int x);

#include "MyVector.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

MyVector::MyVector() {
    sz = 0;
    space = 0;
    arr = nullptr;
}

MyVector::MyVector(int n) {
    sz = n;
    space = n;
    arr = new int [n] {0};
}

int MyVector::get(int i) const {
    return arr[i];
}

void MyVector::set(int i, int x) {
     arr[i] = x;
}

 int MyVector::size() {
    return sz;
}

int MyVector::capacity() {
    return space;
}

void MyVector::push_back(int x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        if (sz == 0) {
            reserve(1);
        }
        else if(sz == space) {
            reserve(2 * space);
            arr[sz-1] = x;
        }
        sz++;
    }
}

void MyVector::reserve(int n) {
    int *temp = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        *(temp + i) = *(arr + i);
        delete[] arr;
        arr = temp;
        space = n;
    }
}
```

Here is my .h file for class declaration.

```
#ifndef MyVector_h
#define MyVector_h

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyVector {
public:
    MyVector();
    MyVector(int n);
    int get(int i) const;
    void set(int i, int x);
    int size();
    int capacity();

    /*Push an element to the end of the array:
     if sz == 0, reserve 1
     else if sz == space, reserve 2 * space
     assign x to the end of the array.
     increment sz*/
    void push_back(int x);
    void reserve(int n);
private:
    int sz;
    int space;
    int *arr;
};

#endif /* MyVector_hpp */
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would recommend to  take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Remove information that is not needed to get help (like the first three rows of this post) and add a  clear concise problem statements. What is wrong ? Also why is this question tagged java and python ?

Comment: I'm actually completely new to stack over flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very close.. You missed one tiny detail...

If you wanted to use pointers you might do something like this

```
void MyVector::push_back(int x)
{
   if (size() == 0)
   { 
      reserve(1);
    } 
    else if (size() == capacity()) 
    {

         reserve(capacity() * 2);
         arr[size() + 1] = x; 
         sz++;

    }
}
```

Using the methods defined within the Class to determine what the next value for the arr entry should be

I was able to get it to compile using the following code for `push_back` and `reserve()`

```
void MyVector::push_back(int x)
{
        if (sz == 0)
        {
            reserve(1);
        }
        else if(sz == space)
        {
            reserve(2 * space);
            arr[sz+1] = x;
        }
        sz++;

}        

void MyVector::reserve(int n)
{       
    int *temp = new int[n];
    for (int i=0; i<size(); i++) {  // copy the old arr to the new 'temp' one
       temp[i] = arr[i];   
    }
        arr = temp;
        space = n;
}
```

Above i simply  create `*temp` as a `new int[n]`  and then set  arr to temp  where n was equal to the new maximum size of the list arr

I also removed both of the for loops as they were resulting in an endless loop happening

---

### **EDIT**

```
#include "MyVector.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


/* This is whats called a constructor.  All of the things entered here will be run at the very start when the object is created */

MyVector::MyVector() {
    sz = 0;   // set the Integer with the name  'sz' to  '0' 
    space = 0;  // set the Integer with the name 'space' to '0'
    arr = nullptr;  /* set the  List of Integers named 'arr'  to 'unassigned' */
}


/* this is a separate constructor which allows for this same object to  be created with the  size and space parameters set to 'n' instead of '0' */

MyVector::MyVector(int n) {
    sz = n;
    space = n;
    arr = new int [n] {0};
}


 /* here is a typed method.  Typed methods are used to return different 
 Integers, Booleans, Double, Arrays, or  Even Objects such as MyVector.   
  */

  /* The type is specified first , in this case it is 'int' 

 * Next,  the class that will have this method  (in this case 'MyVector')

 * Next, the actual method name  (in this case 'get')

  * and Finally the part inside of the parenthesis is the parameters for this method  (int i) which means that whenever you attempt to use this method in the program, you have to include an Integer Object (or a number will work for Integers since its a simple type)


  *  Essentially this adds the ability to just type in  `get(5)`  and return the 5th item in the list (array)  named 'arr'
  */
int MyVector::get(int i) const {
        return arr[i];  /*  return is how you essentially specify the response to send and  'i'  is the parameter of type 'int'  while  the brackets []  are for telling the computer  which entry from 'arr' to pull */
}


/* here is a method with type 'void'  which means that it does not return anything, it only performs operations then finishes */
/*  this method (command) can be sent by simply typing  */
/*   set(5, 3)  and the  5th item in the array list will be set to '3' 
 */

/*  so If i typed this in:  
    set(1, 5); // set the first item to '5'
    set(2, 4); // set the  2nd  item to '4'
    set(3, 3); // ...
    set(4, 2); // ....
    set(5, 1); // set the  5th  item to '1'

    Then the final arr list would be this:  

    arr =  [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]

*/

void MyVector::set(int i, int x) {
     arr[i] = x;
}


// size() is a typed method  that returns whatever 'sz' is set to
 int MyVector::size() {
    return sz;
}


// capacity() is a typed method that returns whatever 'space' is set 
//   to
int MyVector::capacity() {
    return space;
}


// this is the new code I wrote that uses the built-in tools
// to add a new element to the list


   // push back is a short way of saying  'add an item to the end of a list' (its programmer lingo I suppose)
/* here is a non-typed method, so it doesnt return anything.. just performs an operation */

 void MyVector::push_back(int x)
{
   if (size() == 0)   // first check if the result of the size() method is 0
   { 
      reserve(1);  // if it is '0', then we run the non-typed function 'reserve(1)'
    } 
    else if (size() == capacity())   // if the size()  method equals the result of capacity() then..
    {

         reserve(capacity() * 2);  // add additional space to the reserved capacity of the 'arr' list so we can add more items
         arr[size() + 1] = x;   // now that there is more space, we can set the next item which is  1 more than the current size of arr to whatever we specified as 'x' in the parameter for 'push_back'
         sz++;  // finally we increase 'sz'  by 1 so that the size() method will return how many items are in the array 'arr'

    }
}

  // here is the new reserve function that I wrote to properly increase the capacity of 'arr'


void MyVector::reserve(int n)
{       
    int *temp = new int[n];   // create a new blank array with a capacity of  'n'

    for (int i=0; i<size(); i++) {  // copy the old arr to the new 'temp' one
       temp[i] = arr[i];   
    }
        arr = temp;   // replace the 'arr' array with our new 'temp' one
        space = n;  // set the 'space' integer to whatever we specified when we did 'reserve(n)'
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you include those as well?

Comment: Im actually submitting this assignment online on zybooks site. My professor use that for the class.

Comment: Think of arr as like a list of items with numbers attached to them...  arr[1] = Item 1, arr[2] = Item 2, arr[3] = item 3..  etc etc.. So pushing a new entry is another name for  adding an entry to the list, all you have to do is find out how many entries are on the list  (size())  and then add a new one at position  (size() + 1) .. and if you end up making a list that is too big for the paper  then you have to bring out a second piece of paper (which is basically what reserve() does

Comment: If you have time can you explain me the whole program by using comments?. I didn’t quite get it.

Comment: The comments all appear above the code that they describe, just to avoid any confusion..  so you may have to read the method, then re-read the comments above them  in order to fully understand.. dont be afraid to go over it slowly  and re-read anything that doesnt make sense.. its a tough concept to grasp when you first try to put it all together.

Answer (score 0):

Both your `push_back` and `reserver` were wrong, they should be:

```
void MyVector::push_back(int x)
{
    if (sz == 0)
        reserve(1);
    else if (sz == space)
        reserve(2 * space);
    arr[sz] = x;
    sz++;
}

void MyVector::reserve(int n)
{
    int *temp = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        *(temp + i) = *(arr + i);
    delete[] arr;
    space = n;
    arr = temp;
}
```

Comment: You are right. It worked! I was not expecting an error in the reserve function. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SaadArshad "reserve" is still wrong. space+=n; int*temp= new int[space];... And you need a "resize" too.

Comment: Why? In `reserve`, it should be `space = n`, but not `space += n`,  and `int* temp = new int[n]` is correct

Comment: @Red.Wave space = n is correct. space+=n is wrong. also  wrong,int*temp= new int[space].

Comment: @SaadArshad reserve must not decrease the existing capacity of the container nor definitely its current size.